# How to monitor SQL server database table from delphi application

Tags: sql-server, delphi

How can I monitor specific table from Delphi application (real time)
and get new and updated records data ?

Comment: With Bold you have always the latest data in the GUI. You don't have to poll the DB table. More info at http://boldfordelphi.blogspot.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you can use database events / notifications / alerts. The exact term and implementation depends on a DBMS. For details you can check "DBMS alert mechanisms" at [AnyDAC documentation](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Database_Alerts.html).

On a backend you may need to implement triggers for required tables. For some DBMS it is not required. For example, with Firebird a trigger has to call `POST_EVENT` statement. With SQL Server the special set of Query Update Notification API operators must be called to prepare a table.

On a client you should use either special API, either standard SQL query mechanism. For example, with Firebird the special event API must be used. With Oracle a background thread + standard SQL API.

The Delphi implementation depends on a DBMS and data access components. Some examples:

- dbGo (ADO) does not support notifications, when they are implemented using special API;
- dbExpress - the same;
- IBX - use `TIBEvents` with Firebird;
- AnyDAC - use [TADEventAlerter](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/unified-api.html#events). It supports many different mechanisms for many DBMS in a unified way. *Disclosure: AnyDAC is the flagship product of the company I represent.*

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 and up has a notification mechanism... but I don't know of any free component supporting this mechanism...

IF a commercial component is an option [Devart SDAC](http://www.devart.com/sdac/components.html) supports this.

The only other option I see would be to poll (perhaps from a background thread) - but polling is usually something you want to avoid IMO.

Comment: WAITFOR RECEIVE should work in dbGo. That allows to implement event notification using dbGo.